# KSQL KTabke+KTable Join dublicate result anomaly

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

i try inner join ktable and ktable.

**a** and **b** table:

```
 create table a_table(r string, time string) with (Kafka_topic='a', Key='r', Value_format='json');
 create table b_table(r string, time string) with (Kafka_topic='b', Key='r', Value_format='json');
```

inner join **a** and **b** table by r key:

```
create table ab_table as select * from a_table inner join b_table on a_table.r = b_table.r emit changes;
```

1) **use case. insert new data by slow mode**

```
 ksql> insert into a_table values('1','1', 'timeA');
 --wait 5 second;
 ksql> insert into b_table values('1','1', 'timeB');
```

`select * from ab_table emit changes;`  --return 1 row result

`print AB_TABLE from beginning;`        --return 1 row result

2) **use case. insert new data by fast mode**

```
 ksql> insert into a_table values('2','2', 'timeA');insert into b_table values('2','2', 'timeB');

  ksql>  print a from beginning;
    Key format: KAFKA_STRING
    Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
    rowtime: 5/23/20 4:44:06 PM UTC, key: 2, value: {"R":"2","TIME":"timeA"}

   ksql> print b from beginning;
    Key format: KAFKA_STRING
    Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
    rowtime: 5/23/20 4:44:06 PM UTC, key: 2, value: {"R":"2","TIME":"timeB"}
```

`select * from ab_table emit changes;`  --return 1 row result

`print AB_TABLE from beginning;`        --return 2 row result

```
rowtime: 5/23/20 4:44:06 PM UTC, key: 2, value: {"A_TABLE_ROWTIME":1590252246657,"A_TABLE_ROWKEY":"2","A_TABLE_R":"2","A_TABLE_TIME":"timeA","B_TABLE_ROWTIME":1590252246657,"B_TABLE_ROWKEY":"2","
B_TABLE_R":"2","B_TABLE_TIME":"timeB"}
rowtime: 5/23/20 4:44:06 PM UTC, key: 2, value: {"A_TABLE_ROWTIME":1590252246680,"A_TABLE_ROWKEY":"2","A_TABLE_R":"2","A_TABLE_TIME":"timeA","B_TABLE_ROWTIME":1590252246680,"B_TABLE_ROWKEY":"2","
B_TABLE_R":"2","B_TABLE_TIME":"timeB"}
```

What is hell? Why in second use case i have two dublicate row in topic ?

*Update Info about topic \ table*

```
    name                 : B_TABLE
     Field   | Type                      
    -------------------------------------
     ROWTIME | BIGINT           (system) 
     ROWKEY  | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system) 
     R       | VARCHAR(STRING)           
     TIME    | VARCHAR(STRING)  

    name                 : A_TABLE
     Field   | Type                      
    -------------------------------------
     ROWTIME | BIGINT           (system) 
     ROWKEY  | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system) 
     R       | VARCHAR(STRING)           
     TIME    | VARCHAR(STRING)  

    Name                 : AB_TABLE
     Field           | Type                      
    ---------------------------------------------
     ROWTIME         | BIGINT           (system) 
     ROWKEY          | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system) 
     A_TABLE_ROWTIME | BIGINT                    
     A_TABLE_ROWKEY  | VARCHAR(STRING)           
     A_TABLE_R       | VARCHAR(STRING)           
     A_TABLE_TIME    | VARCHAR(STRING)           
     B_TABLE_ROWTIME | BIGINT                    
     B_TABLE_ROWKEY  | VARCHAR(STRING)           
     B_TABLE_R       | VARCHAR(STRING)           
     B_TABLE_TIME    | VARCHAR(STRING)     


topic "a" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1

topic "b" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1

 topic "AB_TABLE" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
```

Comment: To understand what is going on it would help to know what is in the two source tables / topics.

Also, you're using `PRINT x FROM BEGINNING`, which will print from the beginning of the topic, i.e. include historic rows, and using `SELECT * FORM x EMIT CHANGES` which will emit only new lines,i.e. no historic rows.

Comment: i add information about topic \ tables.  I do two equals cases , in "fast case" i get two rows in topic. No prepare date and history.   Anybody can repeat it: up clear cluster , no data , no history no nothing, apply case 1 after up clear cluster, no data, no history no nothing and apply case 2. You will see difference results

Comment: Hey Padavan, what I was after was the content of the two source topics after running case 2.  i.e. what does `PRINT a FROM BEGINNING` and `PRINT b FROM BEGINNING` output?

Comment: @AndrewCoates added  print a from beginning;  print b from beginning;  for  second use case after insert data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked out what's going on here. It's to do with buffering.

By default, ksqlDB is buffering the input from the two source table changelogs, i.e. topic `a` and `b`. (This buffering can be useful to compact all several messages reporting changes to the same key into a single output).

When firing in updates to both tables at once the buffering means that both tables are populated when the buffering is flushed. As both sides of a table-table join result in an output, both input events match each other, resulting in two outputs to topic `AB_TABLE`.

`PRINT AB_TABLE` is correctly showing both of the rows in the changelog.

However, `SELECT * FROM AB_TABLE EMIT CHANGES` is also buffering the input, and this buffering compacts the two changes to a single output.

Buffering can be controlled via the [`cache.max.bytes.buffering`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#cache.max.bytes.buffering). For example, you can turn off the buffering with:

```
-- turn off buffering:
SET 'cache.max.bytes.buffering' = 0;
```

I ran your example again after running the above and there was only a single row in `AB_TABLE` topic.

One could argue that regardless of any buffering the correct output for the table-table join is only a single row. After all, the first row processed should not find a match and the second should.  If you feel strongly about this, then please raise a bug in Github.

Comment: wow thx @AndrewCoates . I try catch this problem 8hours... its amazing what ONE code do difference result...  Its bug!  I start learn english some day ago, if you want, create critical bug in github.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt can see too. I know you work in confluents

Comment: This existing Jira covers the underlying cause: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4609

However, note that if the changelog was materialized the result would be correct.